# Appear dropdown menu when mouseover two seoconds

Tags: javascript

I used DROPDOWNHOVER script and i need to make if mouseover two seconds then appear the menu this is the code before my edit:

```
var Dropdownhover = function (element, options) {
this.options    = options    
this.$element   = $(element)

var that = this

// Defining if navigation tree or single dropdown
this.dropdowns = this.$element.hasClass('dropdown-toggle') ? this.$element.parent().find('.dropdown-menu').parent('.dropdown') : this.$element.find('.dropdown')

this.dropdowns.each(function(){
    $(this).on('mouseenter.bs.dropdownhover', function(e) {
      that.show($(this).children('a, div'))
    })
})
this.dropdowns.each(function(){
    $(this).on('mouseleave.bs.dropdownhover', function(e) {
      that.hide($(this).children('a, div'))
    })
})
}
```

after my edit:

```
var Dropdownhover = function (element, options) {
this.options    = options    
this.$element   = $(element)

var that = this

// Defining if navigation tree or single dropdown
this.dropdowns = this.$element.hasClass('dropdown-toggle') ? this.$element.parent().find('.dropdown-menu').parent('.dropdown') : this.$element.find('.dropdown')
var timeout;
this.dropdowns.each(function(){
   $(this).on('mouseenter.bs.dropdownhover', function(e) {
         timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             that.show($(this).children('a, div'))
         }, 2000)       
    })
})
this.dropdowns.each(function(){
    $(this).on('mouseleave.bs.dropdownhover', function(e) {
      that.hide($(this).children('a, div'))
    })
})
}
```

after my edit it's not working when hover and i must click to open it i try many solutions but failed, What i need when mouseover two seonds then open the dropdown menu.

Any advice ?

Comment: It's a scoping issue, I believe.  Inside your anonymous function `this` is no longer the dropdown.  You probably need to store it before calling the `setTimeout`.  You probably should also check that the mouse is still there, because if they move out during the 2 seconds, it will never hide, as `mouseleave` will have already fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read your code and i can only suggest a way to do that yourself. What you want is a setTimeout function and cancel it if needed:

```
var timeout;
$('.your-Mouse-enter-Menu').mouseenter(function(){
     timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     //Showing The Sub Menu Code
     },2000);
});
$('.your-Mouse-enter-Menu').mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);  //cancel opening submenu if mouse leave
});
```

Comment: Thanks @rorymorirs89 for your edition, but i edited my answer just before your edit submitted.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: https://jsfiddle.net/4eww3pf3/

The JavaScript:

```
var hovered = false; 
$('.my-select').on('mouseenter',function(){
    hovered = true;

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(hovered){
            // do your stuff here
            $('body').append('2 seconds passed!');
        }
    },2000);

}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    hovered = false;
});
```

What is it doing?

A `hovered` variable is defined at the start and set to false. When the `<select>` is hovered, the variable gets set to true, and back to false when unhovered. When the `<select>` is hovered, we set a timeout for 2 seconds; once the 2 seconds has passed we check the state of the `hovered` variable, to find out if we're still hovering on the element or not.